# How to make operation on KeyValuePair in generic way?

Tags: c#, generics

Generic interface:

```
interface IEntity<TKey, TValue>
{
    TKey Key { get; set; }
    TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

My entity class:

```
class MyEntity : IEntity<int, string>
{
    public Key { get; set; }
    public Value { get; set; }
}
```

and a methode to do something with all posible entities in generic way:

```
void MyMethode<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity<int, string> // there is no point, need T parameters
{
    DoEntity(entity.Key, entity.Value);
}
```

i need accomplish something like:

```
void MyMethode<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity<TKey, TValue> // this is not allowed
{
    DoEntity(entity.Key, entity.Value);
}
```

I need to write common database operations on my entities but the problem is i do not know what type Key and Value will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you need to define it like this:

```
void MyMethode<T, TKey, TValue>(T entity) where T : IEntity<TKey, TValue> 
{
    DoEntity(entity.Key, entity.Value);
}
```

But that seems a bit crazy.

The better option may be to have a base `IEntity` which is inherited by `IEntity<TKey, TValue>`.  `IEntity` would simply expose the value and key as object rather than as specific types:

```
interface IEntity
{
    object Key { get; set; }
    object Value { get; set; }
}

interface IEntity<TKey, TValue> : IEntity
{
    TKey Key { get; set; }
    TValue Value { get; set; }
}

class MyEntity : IEntity<int, string>
{
    int IEntity<int, string>.Key
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    string IEntity<int, string>.Value
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    object IEntity.Key
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    object IEntity.Value
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

Then you could simply do this:

```
void MyMethode<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity
{
    DoEntity(entity.Key, entity.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void MyMethode<T, TKey, TValue>(T entity) where T : IEntity<TKey, TValue> 
{
    DoEntity(entity.Key, entity.Value);
}
```